# Remove SQL Instance from list of available servers

Tags: windows-server-2012, sql-server, sql

I had an instance of SQL installed on a secondary drive. That drive failed and was not recoverable. I recovered the database backups. I then reinstalled SQL. I had to remove the SQL instances from the services. That removed them from being seen in SSMS. When I search for any instances available though, that instance still shows that was on the failed drive.

Is there a registry or hack that will let me remove an instance of SQL server from the available servers list?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you seeing this exactly? What command are you using to give you the listing, etc.?

Comment: When a .net application queries the server for any existing instances of sql server. Also, when I open SSMS, it defaults to the old server.

Comment: It's hard telling based on how the drive that failed was setup and how the OS handled that failed drive issue and then it sounds like you did not uninstall the applicable OS SQL Server pointers, etc. for SQL and installed a new instance. Look over https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/ and consider forcefully uninstalled all SQL components and then reinstalling and recovering the DBs from backups again. Even though SQL objects were on separate partition if you didn't uninstall before the new SQL instance then maybe that's the problem.